# Using /blockdata, won't put certain items in chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a maze in Minecraft 1.10 and I have a supply chest at the entrance. I would like to make it so that once you finish the maze, you take a minecart to the beginning and before starting the maze again, you press a button that resets the chest. Here's the code I'm using in the command block:

```
/blockdata -150 4 -1381 {Items:[{Count:16,Slot:0,id:sign},{Count:16,Slot:25,id:sign},{Count:1,Slot:13,Damage:1,id:iron_sword},{Count:2,Slot:15,id:steak},{Count:5,Slot:20,id:cooked_salmon},{Count:10,Slot:8,id:bread}]}
```

It only puts the signs, sword, and bread in the chest. I can't figure out how to get the steak and salmon to work. I tried adding a damage value to those two items, but that didn't make any difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please rename your question to match it contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An item's ID is not necessarily its displayed name (though they sometimes coincide).

The ID for steak is `cooked_beef`, and the ID for cooked salmon is `cooked_fish` with a damage value of `1`. Your fixed command should be:

```
/blockdata -150 4 -1381 {Items:[{Count:16,Slot:0,id:sign},{Count:16,Slot:25,id:sign},{Count:1,Slot:13,Damage:1,id:iron_sword},{Count:2,Slot:15,id:cooked_beef},{Count:5,Slot:20,id:cooked_fish,Damage:1},{Count:10,Slot:8,id:bread}]}
```

There's a list of [Item IDs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Item_IDs) on the wiki. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to enable detailed item tooltips, which then show an item's ID and damage value when hovered over:

[image]

Comment: Now I'm having trouble with a cow spawn egg. Using damage value 92 doesn't seem to work and I'm not getting any damage value from your f3+H shortcut

Comment: @Xanthir Some items (e.g: weapons with enchantments, spawn eggs) have extra data tags. [Here's a wiki page on item data](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format). I believe for a cow egg you'll need to have: `{Count:1,Slot:17,id:spawn_egg,EntityTag:{id:Cow}}`

Answer (score -1):

you could use the /clone command to clone a hidden sample chest.

Comment: As it currently stands, this answer does not fully answer the question that was originally asked. You can _edit_ your response by clicking the "edit" button beneath your answer.